# Are there any alternatives for the python module "random's shuffle function" in micropython?

Tags: python, list, random, raspberry-pi, micropython

I am currently learning micropython.
I know that in python, you can use the “random” module to shuffle a list.
Furthermore, I was wondering if there's any similar function for that in micropython as well, because in the “urandom” module, that function does not exist.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Looks like `urandom` has the `choice()` function, so you could choose a random item, remove it from the original list, and append it to a new list.  Repeat until original list is empty.

Comment: why is this tagged with raspberry-pi?  these are effectively "full computers" that can run a full CPython implementation, not an embedded device that micropython is designed for

Answer (score 0):

micropython can be compiled to have a [`randrange` method available](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/random.html#random.randrange), this can be used to implement the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).  This is a relatively efficient in-place shuffle and can be expressed as:

```
from random import randrange

def shuffle(array):
    "Fisher–Yates shuffle"
    for i in range(len(array)-1, 0, -1):
        j = randrange(i+1)
        array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
```